# Are we ready to use our "New User Welcome"?

Tags: discussion

A draft of a new user welcome has been up for about a week [here](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/i-am-a-new-user-here-at-buddhism-se-what-should-i-know-before-i-post) and has been revised a couple of times to include good suggestions for clarification from the community.

Are there any other suggestions for things to add/delete/revise? Should we wait a bit longer? Or does it look alright enough to begin adding a link to it to comments we leave for new users or even existing users who need some guidance?

Lastly, does anyone know to create a hotkey shortcut which would paste a standard message that included the link into a comment? I took a quick look into the Help Center and didn't spot anything.

Comment: Welcome to Buddhism.SE! Our Welcome page has useful tips for posting questions and answers.
http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/i-am-a-new-user-here-at-buddhism-se-what-should-i-know-before-i-post

Comment: Alternatively, "Welcome to Buddhism.SE! Our [Welcome page](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/1502/254) has etc." Or, just "[Welcome to Buddhism.SE!](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/1502/254)" optionally followed by a specific comment.

Answer (score 2):

I've made some edits, mostly stylistic... I hope they aren't unwelcome - if they are, please feel free to roll back. I also added the "Featured" tag, so the page is already "live" as it were, on the sidebar.

Comment: Edits look good to me. Thank you! Should we copy/paste it over to a new question to get rid of the comments or do you think its alright as it is?

Comment: @Robin111 A third option, given that it's already 'featured' where it is, is: a) you might edit the question e.g. to remove the reference to Skeptics b) decide what to do with my answer, which has examples of how the page is used (actually I've decided: I'll delete it and may repost it as an answer to this question) ... maybe you may want to add something else somewhere to explain how to use the page ... or instead of explaining maybe people will see example of its being used c) flag all existing comments as "obsolete" d) optionally invite new/future comments.

Comment: That was a good idea to flag the comments for removal. Otherwise we'd end up with two versions of the same Question and one might not be updated properly when needed. Also, seeing how the Featured tag works is great. I didn't realize we could have it appear on the sidebar like that. So if there is no easy way to make a macro to paste a standard message in for new users; it will still be easy enough to get the link to make a message each time it's needed. :)

Answer (score 2):

Would it be a good idea to put the "featured" tag back on our [New User Welcome](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/i-am-a-new-user-here-at-buddhism-se-what-should-i-know-before-i-post)? I believe the Community bot removed it. Is it possible to keep multiple featured items on Meta? (If only one can be featured, than maybe it's better to switch it up though.)

Answer (score 1):

> Lastly, does anyone know to create a hotkey shortcut which would paste a standard message

[This moderator](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3073/can-we-help-you-moderate-more#comment9563_3073) uses [this application](https://stackapps.com/q/2116) with [this list of comments](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sklivvz/3497867/raw/proforma.json) (you'd want a different comment or set of comments).

The 'application' is an extension for Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: This is great Chris. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to put the [featured](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured) tag back on our [New User Welcome](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/i-am-a-new-user-here-at-buddhism-se-what-should-i-know-before-i-post)? Community bot comes along from time to time and removes it. But I think without being "featured" it may be overlooked by new users. Thanks!