# How do i insert a hyperlink into a comment?

Tags: support, comments, markdown

I have tried to insert a hyperlink in a comment but i cannot do it.

I want to have the link embedded so one can just press the word and then arrive at the link.

See picture.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Markup for comments is defined [here](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting):

```
_italic_ and **bold** text,
inline `code in backticks`,
and [basic links](http://example.com).
```

Click [here](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/1593/edit) to see the markup for this answer (because this answer uses the same syntax for hyperlinks as the syntax you can use in a comment).

So the text used in the comment which you illustrated is

```
Hello and welcome to Buddhism.SE. What you have under the main question is not clear. We've put together some information to help you get started [here](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/i-am-a-new-user-here-at-buddhism-se-what-should-i-know-before-i-post?).
```

Comment: Beware that there must not be a space between the `]` and the `(`.

Comment: Thanks for the help Chris.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to Chris's answer, if you ever forget, just click on the little orange "help" text beside the comment entry box:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Bhante. I feel a bit embarrassed now that i didnt even see that.