# Guidance on a particular kind of questions

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I recently asked a question from our community here...

[Lord Buddha descending from heavens?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/12903/lord-buddha-descending-from-heavens)

Far as i see this is completely on topic question and it actually bugged me ever since i saw people started making up stories and conspiracy theories on this certain event which even went on to be featured in international television.

I asked this question in hopes that i might find answers.Our good friend **ChrisW** helped me with it but something odd happened to the question,
It was down voted without even leaving a comment to explain why.
So what i'm asking is.....

Is there something wrong with my question *(i'm all ears to advice because this is not the first time)*

I have a feeling some people just race their eyes on questions and instead of really taking their time with it they just go on with their gut feeling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't downvote so I can only guess.

1. One possibility is that having "Alien", "UFO", and "the Buddha" all in the same sentence was unpopular. I thought that was unnecessary and unhelpful, so  I removed it -- in case it was that which was attracting downvotes.
2. "Please inspect these images" is an imperative, it's commanding, giving an order. So just in case anyone resented your telling them what to do, I rephrased that as a neutral/simple question.

   **I also removed the uncessary formatting which makes text seem threatening and harder to read..... What's the matter, are you saying I'm too stupid to notice text unless it's black?**

   In other words, only some trivial changes to the presentation (not the content) of the question.

I didn't notice anything else wrong with the question.

I thought it was an 'iconography' question; and as you can see [from this search](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iconography?sort=newest&pageSize=50) this site doesn't get those questions often (so maybe some people might have thought the topic a bit strange).

Theoretically a question downvote should mean, "This question doesn't show any research effort. It is not clear or not useful." (though in practice people might downvote for any reason they feel like).

---

[Andrei writes](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1827/254)

> I personally also encourage questions requesting to relate specific Buddhist narratives with personal practice.

This doesn't seem to me to be a question about personal practice, i.e. I don't see how an answer to it could help someone to practice Buddhism ... if it were all useless theory and fuel for arguing with UFOlogists then what's the point? Maybe that's why it wasn't upvoted.

---

By the way if anyone does tell you why they downvote, then I recommend you (optionally) thank them for telling you and (definitely) not argue with them. Because, it's easy to downvote without leaving a comment, harder (but helpful, but time-consuming) to leave a comment, and if their explanation just exposes them to an argument then next time they have an incentive to downvote without a comment.

---

Sorry I can't really answer. :-)

Comment: Thank you Chris, You are right about the reason why it was unpopular.