# What is the FAQ for this site and most important of the Meta Discussions regarding defining this site for Relevant New Users

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

What is the FAQ for this site and most important of the Meta discussions regarding defining this site relevant for new users?

Comment: Also maybe a moderator can add faq tag to the relevant questions. This tag can only be added by moderators.

Comment: I re-wrote this meta-topic: [see List of proposed FAQs](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2075/254)

Answer (score 0):

Currently the topics which I considered to be candidates for the FAQ tag are the topics which are tagged [proposed-faq](/questions/tagged/proposed-faq) -- especially:

- [I am a new user here at Buddhism.SE. What should I know before I post?](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/i-am-a-new-user-here-at-buddhism-se-what-should-i-know-before-i-post)
- [Moderation policies for Questions](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1558/moderation-policies-for-questions)