# List of proposed FAQs

Tags: discussion, proposed-faq

I added the [proposed-faq](/questions/tagged/proposed-faq) tag to various topics.

I propose that these topics will be retagged with the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag.

My understanding of how FAQs are created is outlined in [this answer](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/193/535).

I reviewed the current topics on Meta, and I chose this list of topics for the [proposed-faq](/questions/tagged/proposed-faq) tag on the following basis:

- It's clear what policy the topic is proposing or asking about
- There is a clear consensus (based on voting) what the community's majority decision was
- It's a Meta topic which:

  - May be of interest to new users
  - Is used by moderators as their guidance
  - Might be different from the usual policy of other SE sites
  - Is not a topic that's already covered in another [proposed-faq](/questions/tagged/proposed-faq) topic
  - Is not about a topic which is used very infrequently (e.g. deleting accounts, chat, etc.).
  - Is not a [support](/questions/tagged/support) question (whose answer is already known by all experienced SE users), nor a topic which is already explained in one of the standard SE Help topics.

So before I convert these to [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), do you agree with each proposal on this list, or is any proposal disagreeable and needs more discussion?

Do you agree with the list, are there any further topics which you want to add to the list?

Comment: This is a good idea. The main SE site as a FAQ also. We can add this at the end to compliment our FAQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted [proposed-faq](/questions/tagged/proposed-faq) to [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) for various topics, and added a [FAQ index (summary of site policies)](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2106/254) which summarizes them.