# Is this an exclusively theravaden forum?

Tags: discussion

We can downvote questions and project our wrongview onto those questions of other Buddhists ?

Comment: This is not a proper question for this forum and if anywhere belongs in the meta forum.

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is "no". I don't understand the question in the text.

Comment: The main site is for question about Buddhism. Questions and discussions about the site are hosted separately i.e. here on this "meta-site" -- see also the Help section titled [What is "meta"? How does it work?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: Itjs a householder-forum and householding is variable to it's on it holding consumers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question directly... Yes, we can all downvote questions or answers as we see fit, based on our understanding and conscience. Sometimes — yes — that means we project our own 'wrong' views onto a question, but that is the nature of the human beast. We all have 'wrong' views until we manage to rid ourselves of them, and on this forum (at least) there is a reasonable expectation that people will work with our misunderstandings in a kind and generous manner, so that we can start to rid ourselves of 'wrong' views more quickly and easily.

However, there is a difference between 'views' and 'attitudes' that's important to consider. Someone might have an absolute 'right' view — a perfect intellectual understanding of the dharma — and still be far from the goal because they adopt an attitude of anger, bigotry, fear, self-centeredness, or what you will. Attitudes of this sort often have to be moderated, because these attitudes are infectious: rage will bring out rage in others, fear will bring out fear, bigotry bring out bigotry. Even the best question or answer might be closed and removed because the person who wrote it loaded it with triggers and traps that might set the unwary off.

I haven't read enough of your posts to know exactly where you are coming from, but phrases like "[...] project our wrongview onto those questions [...] like a Mahayana" is a slap in the face to anyone who follows a Mahayana path. You don't have to like the Mahayana paths, or respect their teachers, but active disrespect of this sort says less about *their* practice and more about *yours*. No Theravadan teacher I know of would condone his students indulging in such snark both because it hurts the student's progress and because it reflects badly on the school and lineage. If you don't believe me, ask someone in your tradition whose opinion you value.

Be calm and clear. Post from an attitude of compassion and peace, not from righteous indignation. That is easier said than done, I know, but it is best for everyone.

Comment: Yes sir. Thank you for your instruction. There is a lot to be understood. The one who will understand exists in time and This One walks on Earth patiently waiting. You bring up a good question of my lineage? And if they have not revealed themselves? The One who self cherishes has saught Them out but it appears they are in hiding or sick. Regardless, yes wheels of time keep turning and we keep learning every day and hopefully the one who self cherishes will bring joy to her elders.

Comment: @4N4G4M1N: <shrug> Well, I tried...

Answer (score 3):

I think I've understood the question now.

No this isn't an exclusive site.

Someone people (users) study one school, some another, and some several.

We (the community of users on this site) don't want sectarian arguments between schools.

So a question like, "what does school A think of school B?", is difficult to ask on this site -- not quite impossible but those kinds questions are quite rare and carefully asked.

Generally if you ask about school A's doctrine, then you should be asking for school A's view of that doctrine -- i.e. don't ask what school B thinks about school A's doctrine.

Often any question might be answered from the perspective of several schools (which I think is nice, one of the benefits of this site).
But sometimes, when a question is about the specific doctrine of a school, then it should be answered from the perspective of that school only.
Those questions might be tagged using a tag like [theravada](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theravada) or [mahayana](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mahayana) or [tibetan-buddhism](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tibetan-buddhism) or [zen](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zen) or a number of other tags.

If you see a tag like that (for example "[theravada](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theravada)") then a purely Mahayana answer would be off-topic, not an answer to that specific question (and downvoted/deleted).

That is, more or less, how all the several school of Buddhism can be represented on this site -- they coexist, without sectarian arguments.

See also:

- The **Hostile** and **Broad Comparisons** reasons in the [Moderation policies for Questions](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1558/254)
- The **Minimizing controversy** section/topics of the [FAQ index (summary of site policies)](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2106/254).

Comment: In theory this isn't a Buddhist site -- instead it's a site *about* Buddhism, and it's mostly *for* Buddhists but for others too. But please respect Buddhist sensibilities -- so [for example here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodhisattva_vow#Tibet), "Belittling the shravaka vehicle" is behaviour which you should avoid (according to Buddhists), and, must avoid (according to the "rules" of this site). See also the [Code of Conduct](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/conduct) (as well as "[Be nice](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)"] which applies to every site on the SE network.

Comment: Yes okay thank you for taking the time to moderate today. Hopefully by pushing back the presence of the one who self cherishes there will be less discomfort rising to you. May your good fortune increase three times by next Tuesday!

Comment: Have you read the [Dhammapada](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/dhp/dhp.intro.budd.html)? The Pali scriptures are long and a bit difficult to read -- the Dhammapada is quite a good introduction IMO -- accurate and cheerful. Your mentioning "self-cherishing" reminded me of Chapter 10. I don't want to push back the presence of beings, but I want to see people sharing nicely with each other (and being harmless), posts which fit the Q&A format (on this site) -- and ideally something like [right speech](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/search_results.html?q=right+speech). May you be well.

Comment: It feels wrong to read translated texts. It feels as though if one would study such profound teachings they should understand the original language. The one who self cherishes has read some translated texts and will read chapter ten as compassionately advised by The Wise. Thank you

Comment: Several web sites that can help, e.g. to study the Pali side-by-side with an English translation -- especially suttacentral.org, also buddha-vacana.org -- and a lot of the questions on the main site ask about that (e.g. there must be a hundred questions trying to ask exactly what *anatta* means, and other questions asking about all the various other Pali words). I imagine that most people don't try to learn Pali, and that no-one would unless they were already quite interested in the text for some reason.

Comment: Still it takes a while to learn a new language, a good English translation is better than nothing. :-) Also there are different/several translations of the Dhammapada which give slightly different English words. Anyway I think the Dhammapada is used (in Buddhist countries too) as a popular classic or summary -- and introduces various themes. [This edition of the Dhammapada](https://www.tipitaka.net/tipitaka/dhp/verseload.php?verse=001) has the Pali as well as English, if you're curious, and the "origin stories" too (those stories aren't considered "*buddha-vacana*", but the verses are).

Comment: Dear kind one, the sentiment in your last two comments brings tears to they eyes of the one who self cherishes she cries on Earth. Because the one who self cherishes does not deserve the regard of The Wise Ones, is not owed anything by them, the gifts they give bring tears. Priceless gifts richer than any gold or diamond. Given to a wretch. Such behavior only highlights the endless mercy of The Wise.

Comment: It is more soothing to listen to such profound teachings being read aloud by one who loves what they read. Like when listening to yuttadhammo their voice adds dimension to the texts and magnifies what is already present. Andrei the moderator must sound similarly were he to read aloud for us to hear.

Comment: Yes we're fortunate to be able to access the doctrine (the "dharma"), and the people who worked and still work to make it accessible seem heroic and kind, one might be grateful. I used to read to my wife in the last year of her life, I think we both liked doing that.

Answer (score 1):

I was hoping Chris’s answer and your subsequent comment would prove a moment of reflection for you, but I see from your subsequent posts and your slanderous answers that it was not.

You need to stop. Right away. Your tormentor is not someone who practices Theravada, but rather a Mahayana practitioner who wants you to stop doing harm on this forum both to yourself and others. It is quite evident from your erroneous answers that you are a baby Buddhist without a lot of practice or knowledge. You also seem to be quite unskilled in discipline and self-restraint. So stop.

You are causing potential schism and violating the rules of the site and disparaging the Dharma. Take a break, get some water, reflect with some humility and try to use the site to learn and grow your practice or to help others. Of if you simply cannot restrain yourself, then stop posting on the site altogether.

Comment: This was in reference to [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/37140/254) which is now deleted.

Comment: Many of your answers are erroneous from both the viewpoint of Theravada as well as Mahayana and show a lack of understanding of very basic Dharma. At best they are confused. Your motivation is similarly not altruistic, but full of self cherishing. If you had the skill to look inside and check this is what you’d undoubtedly see. Unfortunately, your self-cherishing is at such a level that it will likely overpower any self-assessment. The best thing you could do is adopt an attitude of humility, admit a little doubt about what you think you know and use the site to learn and progress.

Comment: Before you can help others you need to learn to help yourself. And you need to learn what an altruistic motivation truly is and not the facsimile.

Comment: Ok guru thank you for your instruction it is appreciated. Whoever it is you claim has a self-cherishing attitude has renounced volitional harm to all who could be a bodhisattva and to all Buddha's and their families. If the one who self-cherishes has caused pain it was not intentional or volitional. An apology is indeed due to The One who was hurt.

Comment: Please if the one who self cherishes could be so bold to ask guru if tomorrow he will compassionately share even just one sentence of instruction to help one cultivate humility & and an air of doubt. It is the wish of the one who self-cherishes to please beloved guru

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this answer really fits, but because I've just only a couple of days ago downvoted one answer of you, I'll add my remark.
In that "answer" in question I downvoted not because you were critical or something about Theravadins/Theravada (the *contents* of your contribution), but because how you formed it as a ridiculation (because *style* - you were "downvoting" the Theravada by some private perception of some stupidity of the others). However I had even added a comment to my downvoting explaining shortly why I downvoted and also flagged that contribution of yours for moderation to put attention on this.

*Some more explanation: I've been active member in a german buddhist newsgroup from 2002 to about 2010 and the pattern of putting the style of comments towards "the others" completely blocked any positive evolution in the newsgroup. Even trolls made fun out of this by inducing this style of "conversation" to trigger other (usually peaceful) people to engage in this a-social style of conversation.*

Later in the evening, when I came back to BSE here, I noticed moreover that nearly every question on the screen was signed with your icon - maybe it have been 20 contributions in 9 hours, and I really suspected that "4n4g4m1n" might be such a troll-account: who would be able to contribute to so many threads in such a short time with serious content?
Well, I'm not often here in BSE currently, so this all might have been an unlucky accident and the style of conversation which I've critizised has become more a norm nowadays...

So - I do not really know whether this all concerns here your question/complaint. If not, let say me I'm sorry for wrong guess. But at least for supplying a possible context for the other readers here my recollection might be useful.

Comment: Yes the answer which you flagged was [this one](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/37102/254) -- and you were right to flag that and to comment IMO, thank you. I think that "style of conversation" is abnormal still, on this site. 4N4G4M1N is a new user and has posted prolifically but starting only very recently.

Comment: @ChrisW - many thanks for your confirmation! Hope things still go well here (for the sake of ours and our contemporaries) :-)

Comment: Thank you Gottfried - the pure motivation you describe is interpreted as love to the one who self cherishes. Unworthy of anything you have to give. Grateful for what you have already given.