# 2020 Moderator Election - Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Buddhism's Election](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close! The new moderator is:

[image: MOD1_NAME]

They'll be joining the existing crew shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

There was no voting for this election as we just had one candidate.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you Cesar M.

I accept the election results and consent to join as a moderator of Buddhism.SE, in close cooperation with the existing moderators of Buddhism.SE.

I will just repeat my nomination text below:

> I would like to volunteer myself ([ruben2020](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/471/ruben2020?tab=profile)) to be a moderator of
> Buddhism.SE, as I wish to see this site maintained and sustained.
>
> Growth is nice to have, but at the very least, we should maintain what
> we already have, which is a reasonably active community producing good
> quality Buddhism Q&A, in a manner that conforms to the [Code of Conduct](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/conduct)
> and [guidelines](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2106/471) of this community.
>
> The advantage of Buddhism.SE compared to similar sites, is that we
> accept the balanced participation of all Buddhist traditions here. I
> would like to see this continued.
>
> I have been a member of Buddhism.SE for the past 6 years, and have
> been actively participating in recent years.
>
> In terms of moderation, I accept the policy of [A Theory of Moderation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/),
> that moderators are "human exception handlers", who should do as
> little as possible, intervening only when necessary.

Comment: Congratulations, I trust that your efforts will help this universe! :D

Answer (score 5):

This is fine, thanks for volunteering. Make BSE great

Answer (score 2):

This worked out very well i think. I generally like how moderation is nowadays, very quick and i see little to no conflicts. I think this site can outlive us all and remain a valuable evolving commentary.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations to @ruben2020 , to the other moderators and to us all, with keeping this useful site benefitting sentient beings!

Answer (score 0):

`Bhuttā bhogā bhaṭā bhaccā`
   `Vitiṇṇā āpadāsu me`
`Uddhaggā dakkhiṇā dinnā`
   `Atho pañca balī katā`
`Upaṭṭhitā sīlavanto`
   `Saññatā brahmacārino`
`Yadatthaṃ bhogam-iccheyya`
   `Paṇḍito gharam-āvasaṃ`
`So me attho anuppatto`
   `Kataṃ ananutāpiyaṃ`
`Etaṃ anussaraṃ macco`
   `Ariya-dhamme ṭhito naro`
`Idheva naṃ pasaṃsanti`
   `Pecca sagge pamodatīti.`

"My wealth has been enjoyed,
My dependents supported,
protected from calamities by me.
I have given lofty offerings,
and performed the five oblations.
I have provided for the virtuous,
the restrained, leaders of the holy life.
For whatever aim a wise householder
would desire wealth,
that aim I have attained.
I have done what will not lead to future distress."
When this is recollected by a mortal,
a person established in the Dhamma of the Noble Ones,
He is praised in this life
and, after death, rejoices in heaven.